# Trying to use VLOOKUP for two Lookup Values

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup

I have this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(1910921,'All Training Raw Data'!A:C,2,FALSE)
```

The 1910921 refers to a training course but that training course has two ID's. The other being 01929831. I am looking to use the VLOOKUP function to find the email address of who has completed this course. How can I incorporate this second course ID into the VLOOKUP function?

Thanks

Comment: You could use IFERROR to do this: `=Iferror(VLOOKUP(1910921,'All Training Raw Data'!A:C,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(01929831,'All Training Raw Data'!A:C,2,FALSE))`

Comment: Will this not only return the first match that it gets? I mean, if more than one user has done the course, it will always return the email of the first one, right?

Answer (score 0):

If I suppose that your first ID is in the column B and the second one in the column C and the e-mails in the column D, then you can do the following.

In the column A (the example is for A2) put the following formula :`=CONCATENATE(B2,C2)`. Then change your VLOOKUP formula to include the additional ID and look for it in the column A, like this: 
`=VLOOKUP(191092101929831,'All Training Raw Data'!A:D,4,FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

The other user's replies seem to be OK as long as you really need to do it with VLOOKUP function. Although, as I have already commented above I feel like it might not be the best option, as VLOOKUP always returns the value of the first match. Instead you could try using this formula.

```
=IF(MATCH($A1,$I$1:$I$2,0),&B1,"")
```

If you have the courses IDs on I:I column, you check if the course done by the user matches with any of them. If the condition is true, it will return the email from him, which I am guessing it is on the B:B column.

It worked for me so, adapt the ranges to your case and I hope it works for you too.